# Ubuntu 12.10: wifi connected but not working (working on other devices)

Tags: 12.10, wireless

All is said in the title. I'm on Ubuntu 12.10. I went on holidays for one month, where I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10. I just came home today, I turned my computer on, the wifi connected (same password, same settings as before, everything), but the internet doesn't work whatsoever (can't go to any website via Firefox, can't ping google, etc.)

I seem to be able to ping my own IP adress though, if that helps.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's output of `route -n`?

Comment: 0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0    UG    0     0     0    wlan0   //////
169.254.0.0    0.0.0.0    255.255.0.0    U     1000    0    0   0   wlan0  ////
192.168.1.0    0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0  U      9      0    0    wlan0  ////

I can't seem to get linebreaks to work so lines separated by ////
there you go !

Comment: You can [edit] your question and include additional information asked from you =). And when you add terminal outputs, highlight and hit Ctrl+K on them to format them in a nice way. Anyways, it seems that you have a default route set properly. What's the output of `ifconfig`, `ping -c4 192.168.1.1`, `ping -c4 8.8.8.8` and `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280`?